# .NET regex to replace start and end tags based on attribute with same ending tags

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

How can I replace tags based on the attributes when the end tags are the same?

Example:

```
<tag id='bold'><tag id='italic'>Hello World</tag></tag>
```

to

```
<b><i>Hello World</i></b>
```

Is this possible with RegEx or will I need to write a custom parsing method?

Note: This is a simplified example and this is not for use in a HTML browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/284111

Comment: Depending on how complex your html and depth of tags is, you can't write an all-purpose solution in regex. You can describe optional `<tag></tag>` structures within the tag with something among the lines of `<tag>[\s\S]*?(<tag>[\s\S]*?</tag>)*[\s\S]*?</tag>`... and then... another level of optional tag structures within... and so on. Use something else.

Comment: Is the input a well-formed XML file?  If so, I'd seriously consider using XSLT.

Comment: Try this neat regex: `(?s)<tag\s+id='bold'(?:(?:(?!</?tag).)|(?<c><tag\b)|(?<-c>(?<=(\b[^><]*)?)</tag>))+(?(c)(?!))</tag>` and replace with `<b><i>$1</i></b>` ([Test](http://goo.gl/mDk88V)) kidding :] sure a parser solution is better here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with `XElement`, `XPath` and `LINQ`:

```
Dim str As String = "<tag id='bold'><tag id='italic'>Hello World</tag></tag>"
Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version= '1.0'?><root>" + str + "</root>")
Dim query = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//tag")
For Each element In query
   If element.HasAttributes = True Then
        If element.Attribute("id").Value = "italic" Then
           element.Name = "i"
        ElseIf element.Attribute("id").Value = "bold" Then
           element.Name = "b"
        End If
        element.RemoveAttributes()
    End If
Next element
str = xDoc.ToString(System.Xml.Linq.SaveOptions.DisableFormatting).Replace("<root>", String.Empty).Replace("</root>", String.Empty)
```

Output:

[image]

Do not forget to add these `using`s:

```
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.XPath
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not pretty.  I use the regex template below (source forgotten) for some simple yet not Markup Language based syntaxes.  But it works fine here too.

```
         string NestedRegexTemplate =
            @"(?xs)                      # enable eXtended mode (comments/spaces ignored)
                (?<capturedOpen>{0})                      # start of tag
                (?'value'                # named capture
                  (?>                    # don't backtrack
                    (?:
                      ((?!{0})(?!{1}).)+             # not tags
                    | (?'open' {0} )       # count opening bracket
                    | (?'close-open' {1} ) # subtract closing bracket (matches only if open count > 0)
                    )*
                  )
                  (?(open)(?!))          # make sure open is not > 0
                )
                (?<capturedClose>{1})                        # end of tag
            ";

        string test = "<tag id='bold'><tag id='italic'>Hello World</tag></tag>";
        string regex = string.Format(NestedRegexTemplate, @"<\s*tag(\s[^>]*|)>", @"<\s*/\s*tag\s*>");
        var match = Regex.Match(test, regex);
        while (match.Success)
        {
            var capturedOpen = match.Groups["capturedOpen"];
            var capturedClose = match.Groups["capturedClose"];

            if (capturedOpen.Value.Contains("'bold'"))
            {
                test = test.Remove(capturedClose.Index, capturedClose.Length);
                test = test.Insert(capturedClose.Index, "</b>");
                test = test.Remove(capturedOpen.Index, capturedOpen.Length);
                test = test.Insert(capturedOpen.Index, "<b>");
            }
            else if (capturedOpen.Value.Contains("'italic'"))
            {
                test = test.Remove(capturedClose.Index, capturedClose.Length);
                test = test.Insert(capturedClose.Index, "</i>");
                test = test.Remove(capturedOpen.Index, capturedOpen.Length);
                test = test.Insert(capturedOpen.Index, "<i>");
            }

            match = Regex.Match(test, regex);
        }
```